# What Islam says about praising others?

Tags: practical-islam

Assalamu alaikum,

At the starting of the Qur'an is it was said that all praise be to Allah, so is there anything said about it in more detail? We praises people without knowing or without that knowledge. Is all good praises and names are only for Allah? If so, then what should we call other people when appreciating them about their good deeds and potentials?

JazakAllah khair

Answer (score 0):

The explanation of praise and difference between it and thanking has details more than what is required for answering your question, thus I will focus on your points.

**Islam** clearly **encourages** Muslims **to praise other people** for the good they have or the good they do, with what they deserve:

> Narrated Abu Hurayrah: The Prophet
> (ﷺ) said: He who does not thank the people is not thankful to Allah.
> [Sunan Abi Dawud 4811](http://sunnah.com/abudawud/43/39)

### all praise be to Allah

Because he is the creator and the original reason for any good happens to any creature.

### No contradiction

All praise to Allah even the ones you pay for people, because Allah is the one allowed that good to happen by that person and allowed it to exist at the first place.

Comment: Wonderful answer. It is not wrong to praise ppl

Comment: You say there's a difference between praising and thanking. Then don't explain it. And the only reference your answer is built on is about thanking. As pointed out in the comments this question is a duplicate and has already some answers. Therefore it would be more constructive to elaborate your answer and post it there.